# Why is Android:Run Gradle task being executed during Desktop:Run task in IntelliJ 2016.2?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, gradle, libgdx

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.3 (normal x64 IDE, not Android Studio) on windows 10, with 1.8 JDK.
I have set up a libgdx project with android and desktop modules.
When trying to run Desktop:Run, Android:Run is also executed beforehand.
I have checked the build file in the main project folder, as well as the modules Core, Android, and Desktop.
Android is not specified as a dependency of Desktop.

Weirdly, If I open a completely unrelated project (though it has a similar project structure) in a separate window, I can suddenly execute Desktop:Run normally for the primary project
.
The projects do not rely on each-other, so I am guessing that the gradle wrapper is borrowing settings from the second unrelated project when trying to execute tasks for the original project.

Completely confused here...any ideas what is going on?

(note: I can provide gradle config files, but I have checked each of them against a functioning project using the Notepad++ Compare-plugin, and there are no differences in the gradle .build files. It must be a configuration set in the IDE but I am not sure where to look.)

Comment: Instead of just simply down-voting and leaving me in the dark, please leave an explanation as to why you are doing so. I have researched this problem for several days, and looked through all the IDE settings, but can't figure it out. I have made an honest effort to figure this out, and I don't appreciate down-votes without an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Ok...it seems that while I used to be able to simply specify "run" as the task in the run configuration, this is no longer working, and I must fully define the task name: ":Desktop:run"

Comment: This is very strange. When I double click `:desktop:run` in the Gradle window in Android Studio, I get an incorrect Run Configuration which executes `:run` in all Gradle projects, not just the one which is shown in the Run Configuration. After I edit the task in the Run Configuration manually as described here, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying ":desktop:run" in the LibGDX project run configuration, in place of "run" worked for me too.
This appears to be tracked in IntelliJ's tracker under this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-160189